# I can't access a placeholder-prefixed route because of a conflict

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, url-routing

[image]

Here are the routes I'm working on (generated by `apiResource` Laravel's method). As you can see, there are 1 or 2 placeholders. My issue comes when I try to GET `anything/customers`. It raises this exception:

`Missing required parameters for [Route: json-api.customers.show] [URI: {tenant}/customers/{customer}].`

Unless I'm missing an obvious thing, the router should accept this request because `anything/customers` matches `{tenant}/customers`.

I'd really appreciate any help about that. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I add this code to answer a comment but I don't think it will help to understand this issue (I'm implementing a package based on JSON:API spec).

```php
protected function jsonApiResource()
{
    return function (string $class, array $options = []) {
        if ($routerMethod = $class::getRouterMethod()) {
            $middleware = array_merge(
                $options['middleware'] ?? [],
                $class::getApiMiddlewares()
            );

            $as = $options['as'] ?? '';

            $prefix = $class::getRouterPrefix();

            $this->group(compact('middleware', 'as', 'prefix'), function ($router) use ($class, $routerMethod, $options) {
                $alias      = $class::getAlias();
                $controller = $class::getControllerClass();

                $router->{$routerMethod}(
                    $alias,
                    $controller,
                    Arr::only($options, ['only', 'except'])
                );

                foreach ($class::getRelationsRoutes() as $relationshipName => $relationshipMethods) {
                    $router->resourceRelationship(
                        $alias,
                        $relationshipName,
                        $controller,
                        $relationshipMethods
                    );
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code defining the routes?

Comment: Code added but I'm afraid it won't help you

Comment: OK, that's a lot more complex than I thought :)  I would try to debug the router starting at `Illuminate\Routing\Router::findRoute()`

Comment: What would you like me to dump?

Comment: Where does this package get the list of routenames? Does it load it from the db? ( I know it is very important to define routes in the correct order, otherwise the wrong one will be triggered)

Comment: I don't have any control over the generation order because these routes come from `apiResource` router method of Laravel itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after 3 days on that, I found out the origin, the exception message misled me.

```php
/**
     * Get links to fetch the model or one of its relationships.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $relationshipName
     * @return array
     */
    public function getApiLinks(string $relationshipName = null)
    {
        $urlGenerator   = app()->make('url');
        $identifiers    = $this->getApiIdentifiers();

        if ($relationshipName) {
            return [
                'self'      => $urlGenerator->jsonApiRelationship($identifiers['type'], $identifiers['id'], $relationshipName, 'index'),
                'related'   => $urlGenerator->jsonApiRelationship($identifiers['type'], $identifiers['id'], $relationshipName, 'related')
            ];
        }

        return [
            'self' => $urlGenerator->route(
                'json-api.'.$identifiers['type'].'.show',
                [ Str::singular($identifiers['type']) => $identifiers['id'] ]
        ];
```

The issue came from the URL generation on the return, any additional URL placeholder wouldn't be included into the array and by the way led to this message.

With this fix, it works now:

```
/**
     * Get links to fetch the model or one of its relationships.
     *
     * @param  string|null  $relationshipName
     * @return array
     */
    public function getApiLinks(string $relationshipName = null)
    {
        $urlGenerator   = app()->make('url');
        $identifiers    = $this->getApiIdentifiers();
        $otherParams    = $urlGenerator->getRequest()->route()->parameters();

        if ($relationshipName) {
            return [
                'self'      => $urlGenerator->jsonApiRelationship($identifiers['type'], $identifiers['id'], $relationshipName, 'index', $otherParams),
                'related'   => $urlGenerator->jsonApiRelationship($identifiers['type'], $identifiers['id'], $relationshipName, 'related', $otherParams)
            ];
        }

        return [
            'self' => $urlGenerator->route(
                'json-api.'.$identifiers['type'].'.show',
                array_merge(
                    $otherParams,
                    [ Str::singular($identifiers['type']) => $identifiers['id'] ]
                )
            )
        ];
    }
```

Thanks anyway for your help!

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty hard for the router to determine with a variable on either side.  It might help to add a solid path before the first `/` like `something/{tenant}/customers`.  However, the reason for the error is most likely that the first GET path to hit the router according to your routes list is:

```
{tenant}/customers/{customer}
```

Because this is **first**, Laravel *expects there to be a customer variable coming in*.  If you place this line higher up, it won't expect the variable every time.  So:

```
{tenant}/customers/{customer}
{tenant}/customers/
```

This should help... but it may not due to the wildcards on either side - you'll have to test.

If you have these set as a `resource`, I suggest you break them out to individual route methods to test

Comment: I didn't achieve to reproduce the issue with broken routes `Route::get('{tenant}/tests', function () {return response()->json(['test0']);});
Route::get('{tenant}/tests/{test1}', function () {return response()->json(['test1']);});` works and its reverse too (they both respond test0). Pack them into a prefixed route group works too...

Comment: I think this means that the issue is possibly combined to the two things I noted above.  Perhaps because of the wildcard first word, you may be unknowingly duplicating the first word of another route.  IE {Route1}/customers  is actually already a hard coded route Route1/customers somewhere else.  I would test your current `resource` with a word infront of `{tenant}` such as `testing/{tenant}/customers` etc.

Comment: I already tried this before opening this issue, and the problem also raises here unfortunately. `Missing required parameters for [Route: json-api.customers.show] [URI: testing/{tenant}/customers/{customer}].`

Comment: Shoot, that's unfortunate.  My only suggestion is to combine the two things - add the first word (testing) and break them out from the `resource`.  I have had this happen before and it was generally one or the other of these two things that I note above (or both).

Comment: I'll try some tests and let you know if I find out a working way. Thanks anyway.